# Multiple Navigation bars flutter

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview, appbar

Can anyone give any insight into how to implement two Navigation bars (a custom Navigation bar embedded into the AppBar that is in a TabView of the bottom Navigation Bar)?

Ex:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bottom property of an `appbar` like below. And it would be nested inside a bottom tabbar you create.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('you can put your search here'),
          bottom: Tabbar(
            tabs:<Widget>[
                   Text('tab1'),
                   Text('tab2')
                 ]
          )
        ),
        body: new TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
            Screen1(),
            Screen2(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```